# Bibtex style for "Statistics and Computing"

Tags: bibtex, journal-publishing, journal

I would like to create a bibtex style which answers the requirements of Statistics and Computing journal. How could I do that?

Here is an example of how the bibliography should look like:

> Journal article:
>
> Hamburger, C.: Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of partial differential equations. Ann. Mat. Pura Appl. 169, 321–354 (1995)
>
> Book:
>
> Geddes, K.O., Czapor, S.R., Labahn, G.: Algorithms for Computer Algebra. Kluwer, Boston (1992)
>
> Book chapter:
>
> Broy, M.: Software engineering — from auxiliary to key technologies. In: Broy, M., Denert, E. (eds.) Software Pioneers, pp. 10–13. Springer, Heidelberg (2002)

In the text, the references should be as follows:

> Negotiation research spans many disciplines (Hamburger 1995).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How about labels? There's none in your example.

Comment: Looking at "Instructions for Authors" (following a link from http://www.springer.com/statistics/computational+statistics/journal/11222) tells us that the publisher provides LaTeX support files you should use. Have you tried the bibtex style files included in that package?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. But the bibtex files included do not correspond

Comment: Do not correspond to what? Could you provide an example and a link to that `bst` file?

Comment: The bst files provided by springer does not correspond to what the bibtex style the journal is asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a custom bibliography style with [`makebst`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/makebst). With a standard `article` document class, the result looks like this:
[image: Output of custom bibliography style, standard document class]

Document class `svjour3` from the publisher of the journal alters the citation style (by using `\bibpunct`) to drop the comma between author and year:
[image: Output of custom bibliography style, publisher's document class]

*Code of the example document*

```
%\documentclass[natbib]{svjour3} % File available from Springer
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib} % loaded by svjour3 with natbib option
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{hamburger1995quasimonotonicity,
  title={Quasimonotonicity, Regularity and Duality for Nonlinear Systems of Partial Differential Equations},
  author={Hamburger, Christoph},
  journal={Ann. Mat. Pura Appl.},
  volume={169},
  pages={321--354},
  year={1995},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@book{geddes1992algorithms,
  title={Algorithms for Computer Algebra},
  author={Geddes, K O and Czapor, S R and Labahn, G},
  year={1992},
  publisher={Kluwer},
  address={Boston}
}
@InCollection{broy2002software,
  author={Broy, Manfred},
  title={Software engineering -- from auxiliary to key technologies},
  booktitle={Software Pioneers},
  publisher={Springer},
  address={Heidelberg},
  pages={10--13},
  year={2002},
  editor={Broy, Manfred and Denert, Ernst}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{spcustom}

Parenthetical citation to an article
\citep{hamburger1995quasimonotonicity}.  Textual citation to a book,
as \citet{geddes1992algorithms}.  Something ``InCollection''
\citep{broy2002software}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

*Source of the bibliography style*. Run it through `tex` to produce bibtex style file `spcustom.bst`. Customize if necessary, then repeat TeXing. All the commented lines are preserved to facilitate changes.

```
%% Driver file to produce spcustom.bst from merlin.mbs
%% Generated with makebst, version 4.1 (2003/09/08)
%% Produced on 2014/07/08 at 16:24
%% Manually edited on 2014/07/09
%% TeXing this creates bibtex style file spcustom.bst
%% 
\input docstrip

\preamble
----------------------------------------
*** Statistics and Computing ***

\endpreamble

\postamble
End of customized bst file
\endpostamble

\keepsilent

\askforoverwritefalse
\def\MBopts{\from{merlin.mbs}{%
%EXTERNAL FILES:
%Name of language file: \cfile=.
%No included files.
%INTERNAL LANGUAGE SUPPORT (if no external language file)
    %: (def) English
% babel,%: Babel
%--------------------
%STYLE OF CITATIONS:
%   %: (def) Numerical
  ay,%: Author-year
% alph,%: Alpha style, Jon90 or JWB90
% alph,alf-1,%: Alpha style, Jon90
% alph,alf-f,%: Alpha style, Jones90
% cite,%: Cite key
%--------------------
%HTML OUTPUT (if non author-year citations)
%   %: (def) Normal LaTeX
% html,%: Hypertext
% html,htlist,%: Hypertext list
% html,htdes,%: Hypertext with keys
%--------------------
%AUTHOR--YEAR SUPPORT SYSTEM (if author-year citations)
  nat,%: Natbib
%   %: (def) Older Natbib
% alk,%: Apalike
% har,%: Harvard
% ast,%: Astronomy
% cay,%: Chicago
% nmd,%: Named
% cn,%: Author-date
%--------------------
%HARVARD EXTENSIONS INCLUDED (if Harvard support selected)
% harnm,%: With Harvard extensions
%   %: (def) Older Harvard
%--------------------
%LANGUAGE FIELD
%   %: (def) No language field
  lang,%: Add language field
%--------------------
%ANNOTATIONS:
    %: (def) No annotations
% annote,%: Annotations
%--------------------
%PRESENTATIONS:
    %: (def) Do not add presentation type
% pres,%: Add presentation, speaker not highlighted
% pres,pres-bf,%: Presentation, speaker bold face
% pres,pres-it,%: Presentaion, speaker italic
% pres,pres-sc,%: Presentaion, speaker in small caps
%--------------------
%ORDERING OF REFERENCES (if non-author/year and non-alph)
%   %: (def) Alphabetical
% seq-no,%: Citation order
% seq-yr,%: Year ordered
% seq-yrr,%: Reverse year ordered
%--------------------
%ORDERING OF REFERENCES (if author-year citations)
    %: (def) Alphabetical
% seq-lab,%: By label
% seq-labc,%: By label and cite order
% seq-key,%: By label and cite key
% seq-yr,%: Year ordered
% seq-yrr,%: Reverse year ordered
% seq-no,%: Citation order
%--------------------
%ORDER ON VON PART (if not citation order)
    %: (def) Sort on von part
% vonx,%: Sort without von part
%--------------------
%IGNORE FIRST NAMES (if author-year citations)
    %: (def) Respect first names
% xintls,%: Sort on surname only
%--------------------
%AUTHOR NAMES:
% ed-au,%: Full, surname last
% nm-revf,%: Full, surname first
% nm-init,ed-au,%: Initials + surname
% nm-rev,%: Surname + initials
% nm-rv,%: Surname + dotless initials
  nm-rvvc,%: Surname + comma + spaceless initials
% nm-rvx,%: Surname + pure initials
% nm-rvcx,%: Surname + comma + pure initials
% nm-rvv,%: Surname + spaceless initials
% nm-rev1,%: Only first name reversed, initials
% nm-revv1,%: First name reversed, with full names
%--------------------
%EDITOR NAMES IN COLLECTIONS (if author names reversed)
  ed-rev,%: Editor names reversed
%--------------------
%POSITION OF JUNIOR (if author names reversed)
% jnrlst,%: Junior comes last
%   %: (def) Junior between
%--------------------
%JUNIOR PART IN THE CITATION (if author-year citations)
    %: (def) No `junior' part in the citations
% jnrlab,%: `Junior' in citations
%--------------------
%PUNCTUATION BETWEEN AUTHOR NAMES:
    %: (def) Author names separated by commas
% aunm-semi,%: Names separated by semi-colon
% aunm-sl,%: Names separated by slash
%--------------------
%ADJACENT REFERENCES WITH REPEATED NAMES:
    %: (def) Author/editor names always present
% nmdash,%: Repeated author/editor names replaced by dash
% nmdash,nmd-2,%: Repeated author/editor names replaced by 2 dashes
% nmdash,nmd-3,%: Repeated author/editor names replaced by 3 dashes
%--------------------
%NUMBER OF AUTHORS IN BIBLIOGRAPHY:
    %: (def) All authors
% nmlm,%: Limited authors
%--------------------
%AUTHORS IN CITATIONS:
    %: (def) One author et al
% mcite,%: Some other truncation scheme
%--------------------
%MAX AUTHORS BEFORE ET AL: (if regular cite not selected)
% mct-1,%: One et al
% mct-2,%: One, Two et al
% mct-3,%: One, Two, Three et al
% mct-4,%: One, Two, Three, Four et al
% mct-5,%: One, Two, Three, Four, Five et al
% mct-6,%: One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six et al
%--------------------
%MAX AUTHORS WITHOUT ET AL: (if regular cite not selected)
% mct-x2,%: Two authors without truncating
% mct-x3,%: Three authors
% mct-x4,%: Four authors
% mct-x5,%: Five authors
% mct-x6,%: Six authors
%--------------------
%TYPEFACE FOR AUTHORS IN LIST OF REFERENCES:
    %: (def) Normal font for author names
% nmft,nmft-sc,%: Small caps authors
% nmft,nmft-it,%: Italic authors
% nmft,nmft-bf,%: Bold authors
% nmft,nmft-def,%: User defined author font
%--------------------
%FONT FOR FIRST NAMES (if non-default font for authors)
%   %: (def) First names same font as surnames
% fnm-rm,%: First names in normal font
% fnm-def,%: First names in user defined font
%--------------------
%EDITOR NAMES IN INCOLLECTION ETC:
%   %: (def) Editors incollection normal font
% nmfted,%: Editors incollection like authors
%--------------------
%FONT FOR `AND' IN LIST:
%   %: (def) `And' in author font
% nmand-rm,%: `And' in normal font
%--------------------
%FONT OF CITATION LABELS IN TEXT (if author-year citations)
    %: (def) Cited authors plain
% lab,lab-it,%: Cited authors italic
% lab,lab-sc,%: Cited authors small caps
% lab,lab-bf,%: Cited authors bold
% lab,lab-def,%: User defined citation font
%--------------------
%FONT FOR `AND' IN CITATIONS (if non-default font for citation lables)
%   %: (def) Cited `and' in author font
% and-rm,%: Cited `and' in normal font
%--------------------
%FONT OF EXTRA LABEL (The extra letter on the year)
    %: (def) Extra label plain
% xlab-it,%: Extra label italic
%--------------------
%LABEL WHEN AUTHORS MISSING (if author-year citations)
  keyxyr,%: Year blank when KEY replaces missing author
%   %: (def) Year included when KEY replaces missing author
%--------------------
%MISSING DATE (if author-year citations)
%   %: (def) Missing date set to ????
  blkyear,%: Missing date left blank
%--------------------
%DATE POSITION:
    %: (def) Date at end
% dt-beg,%: Date after authors
% dt-jnl,%: Date part of journal spec.
% dt-end,%: Date at very end
%--------------------
%DATE FORMAT (if non author-year citations)
%   %: (def) Plain month and year
% yr-par,%: Date in parentheses
% yr-brk,%: Date in brackets
% yr-col,%: Date preceded by colon
% yr-per,%: Date preceded by period
% yr-com,%: Date preceded by comma
% yr-blk,%: Date preceded by space
%--------------------
%SUPPRESS MONTH:
%   %: (def) Date is month and year
% xmth,%: Date is year only
%--------------------
%REVERSED DATE (if including month)
%   %: (def) Date as month year
% dtrev,%: Date as year month
%--------------------
%DATE FORMAT (if author-year citations)
%   %: (def) Year plain
  yr-par,%: Year in parentheses
% yr-brk,%: Year in brackets
% yr-col,%: Year preceded by colon
% yr-per,%: Year preceded by period
% yr-com,%: Date preceded by comma
% yr-blk,%: Year preceded by space
%--------------------
%INCLUDE MONTHS:
    %: (def) Date is year only
% aymth,%: Include month in date
%--------------------
%REVERSED DATE (if including month)
%   %: (def) Date as month year
% dtrev,%: Date as year month
%--------------------
%DATE PUNCTUATION (if date not at end)
%   %: (def) Date with standard block punctuation
% yrp-col,%: Colon after date
% yrp-semi,%: Semi-colon after date
% yrp-per,%: Period after date
% yrp-x,%: No punct. after date
%--------------------
%BLANK AFTER DATE:
%   %: (def) Space after date
% yrpp-xsp,%: No space after date
%--------------------
%DATE FONT:
    %: (def) Date in normal font
% dtbf,%: Date in bold face
%--------------------
%TRUNCATE YEAR (if author-year citations)
  note-yr,%: Year text full
%   %: (def) Year truncated
%--------------------
%TITLE OF ARTICLE:
    %: (def) Title plain
% tit-it,%: Title italic
% tit-qq,qt-s,%: Title and punctuation in single quotes
% tit-qq,%: Title and punctuation in double quotes
% tit-qq,qt-g,%: Title and punctuation in guillemets
% tit-qq,qt-s,qx,%: Title in single quotes
% tit-qq,qx,%: Title in double quotes
% tit-qq,qt-g,qx,%: Title in guillemets
%--------------------
%COLLECTION/PROCEEDINGS TITLES (if quoted title)
% bt-qq,%: Quote collection and proceedings titles
%   %: (def) Collection and proceedings titles not in quotes
%--------------------
%CAPITALIZATION OF ARTICLE TITLE:
    %: (def) Sentence style
% atit-u,%: Title style
%--------------------
%ARTICLE TITLE PRESENT:
    %: (def) Article title present
% jtit-x,%: No article title
%--------------------
%JOURNAL NAMES:
    %: (def) Periods in journal names
% jxper,%: Dotless journal names
%--------------------
%JOURNAL NAME FONT:
%   %: (def) Journal name italics
  jttl-rm,%: Journal name normal
%--------------------
%THESIS TITLE:
    %: (def) Thesis titles like books
% thtit-a,%: Thesis title like article
% thtit-x,%: No thesis title
%--------------------
%TECHNICAL REPORT TITLE:
    %: (def) Tech. report title like articles
% trtit-b,%: Tech. report title like books
%--------------------
%TECHNICAL REPORT NUMBER:
    %: (def) Tech. report and number plain
% trnum-it,%: Tech. report and number italic
%--------------------
%JOURNAL VOLUME:
%   %: (def) Volume plain
% vol-it,%: Volume italic
  vol-bf,%: Volume bold
% vol-2bf,%: Volume and number bold
%--------------------
%JOURNAL VOL AND NUMBER:
    %: (def) Journal vol(num)
% vnum-sp,%: Journal vol (num)
% vnum-cm,%: Journal vol, num
% vnum-nr,%: Journal vol, no. num
% vnum-h,%: Journal vol, \# number
% vnum-b,%: Journal vol number
% vnum-x,%: Journal vol, without number
%--------------------
%VOLUME PUNCTUATION:
%   %: (def) Volume with colon
% volp-sp,%: Volume with colon and space
% volp-semi,%: Volume with semi-colon
  volp-com,%: Volume with comma
% volp-blk,%: Volume with blank
%--------------------
%YEAR IN JOURNAL SPECIFICATION:
    %: (def) Journal year like others
% jdt-v,%: Journal vol(year)
% jdt-vs,%: Journal vol (year)
% jdt-p,%: Year with pages
% jdt-pc,%: Year, comma, pages
%--------------------
%PAGE NUMBERS:
    %: (def) Start and stop page numbers
% jpg-1,%: Only start page number
%--------------------
%LARGE PAGE NUMBERS:
    %: (def) No separators for large page numbers
% pgsep-c,%: Comma inserted over 9999
% pgsep-s,%: Thin space inserted over 9999
% pgsep-p,%: Period inserted over 9999
%--------------------
%WORD `PAGE' IN ARTICLES:
    %: (def) Article pages numbers only
% jwdpg,%: Include `page' in articles
%--------------------
%POSITION OF PAGES:
    %: (def) Pages given mid text
% pp-last,%: Pages at end
%--------------------
%WORD `VOLUME' IN ARTICLES:
    %: (def) Article volume as number only
% jwdvol,%: Include `volume' in articles
%--------------------
%NUMBER AND SERIES FOR COLLECTIONS:
% num-xser,%: Allows number without series
    %: (def) Standard BibTeX
%--------------------
%POSITION OF NUMBER AND SERIES:
    %: (def) After chapter and pages
% numser,%: Just before publisher
%--------------------
%VOLUME AND SERIES FOR BOOKS/COLLECTIONS:
    %: (def) Vol. 23 of Series
% ser-vol,%: Series, vol. 23
%--------------------
%POSITION OF VOLUME AND SERIES FOR INCOLLECTIONS:
    %: (def) Series and volume after the editors
% ser-ed,%: Series and volume after booktitle
%--------------------
%JOURNAL NAME PUNCTUATION:
%   %: (def) Comma after journal
  jnm-x,%: Space after journal
%--------------------
%BOOK TITLE:
%   %: (def) Book title italic
  btit-rm,bt-rm,%: Book title plain
%--------------------
%PAGES IN BOOKS:
    %: (def) Pages in book plain
% bkpg-par,%: Pages in book in parentheses
% bkpg-x,%: Pages in book bare
%--------------------
%TOTAL PAGES OF A BOOK:
    %: (def) Total book pages not printed
% pg-bk,%: For book: 345 pages
% pg-bk,pg-pre,%: Total book pages before publisher
%--------------------
%PUBLISHER ADDRESS:
    %: (def) Publisher, address
% add-pub,%: Address: Publisher
%--------------------
%PUBLISHER IN PARENTHESES:
    %: (def) Publisher as normal block
% pub-par,%: Publisher in parentheses
% pub-date,%: Publisher and date in parentheses
% pub-date,pub-xc,%: Publisher and date in parentheses, no comma
% pub-date,pub-xpar,%: Publisher and date without parentheses
% pub-date,pub-xpar,pub-xc,%: Publisher and date, no parentheses, no comma
%--------------------
%PUBLISHER POSITION:
    %: (def) Publisher after chapter, pages
% pre-pub,%: Publisher before chapter, pages
% pre-edn,%: Publisher after edition
%--------------------
%ISBN NUMBER:
% isbn,%: Include ISBN
    %: (def) No ISBN
%--------------------
%ISSN NUMBER:
% issn,%: Include ISSN
    %: (def) No ISSN
%--------------------
%DOI NUMBER:
  doi,%: Include DOI
% url-doi,%: Format DOI as URL //dx.doi.org/doi
% agu-doi,doi,%: Insert DOI AGU style
%   %: (def) No DOI
%--------------------
%`EDITOR' AFTER NAMES (EDITED BOOKS WITHOUT AUTHORS):
%   %: (def) Word `editor' after name
% edpar,%: `Name (editor),'
% edpar,bkedcap,%: `Name (Editor),'
% edparc,%: `Name, (editor)'
% edparc,bkedcap,%: `Name, (Editor)'
  edparxc,%: `Name (editor)'
% edparxc,bkedcap,%: `Name (Editor)'
%--------------------
%EDITOR IN COLLECTIONS:
    %: (def) Same as for edited book
% edby,%: In booktitle, edited by .. 
% edby-par,%: In booktitle (edited by ..)
% edby-parc,%: In booktitle, (edited by ..)
% edby,edbyx,%: In booktitle, editor ..
% edby,edbyw,%: In booktitle, (editor) ..
% edby-par,edbyx,%: In booktitle (editor..)
% edby-parc,edbyx,%: In booktitle, (editor..)
% edby,edbyy,%: In booktitle, .., editor
% edby-par,edbyy,%: In booktitle (.., editor)
%--------------------
%CAPITALIZE `EDITOR' OR `EDITED BY' (if editor capitalizable)
%   %: (def) `(editor,..)' or `(edited by..)'
% edcap,%: `(Editor,..)' or `(Edited by..)'
%--------------------
%PUNCTUATION BETWEEN SECTIONS (BLOCKS):
    %: (def) \newblock after blocks
% blk-com,%: Comma between blocks
% blk-com,com-semi,%: Semi-colon between blocks
% blk-com,com-blank,%: Blanks between blocks
% blk-tit,%: Period after titles of articles, books, etc
% blk-tit,tit-col,%: Colon after titles of articles, books, etc
% blk-tita,%: Period after titles of articles
% blk-tita,tit-col,%: Colon after titles of articles
%--------------------
%PUNCTUATION BEFORE NOTES (if not using \newblock)
%   %: (def) Notes have regular punctuation
% blknt,%: Notes preceded by period
%--------------------
%PUNCTUATION AFTER AUTHORS:
%   %: (def) Author block normal
  au-col,%: Author block with colon
%--------------------
%PUNCTUATION AFTER `IN':
%   %: (def) Space after `in'
  in-col,%: Colon after `in'
% in-it,%: Italic `in'
% in-col,in-it,%: Italic `in' and colon
% in-x,%: No word `in'
%--------------------
%`IN' WITH JOURNAL NAMES (if using 'in' with collections)
    %: (def) No `in' before journal name
% injnl,%: Add `in' before journal name
%--------------------
%FINAL PUNCTUATION:
%   %: (def) Period at very end
  fin-bare,%: No period at end
%--------------------
%ABBREVIATE WORD `PAGES' (if not using external language file)
%   %: (def) `Page(s)'
  pp,%: `Page' abbreviated
% ppx,%: `Page' omitted
%--------------------
%ABBREVIATE WORD `EDITORS':
%   %: (def) `Editor(s)'
  ed,%: `Editor' abbreviated
%--------------------
%OTHER ABBREVIATIONS:
%   %: (def) No abbreviations
  abr,%: Abbreviations
%--------------------
%ABBREVIATION FOR `EDITION' (if abbreviating words)
%   %: (def) `Edition' abbreviated as `edn'
  ednx,%: `Edition' abbreviated as `ed'
%--------------------
%MONTHS WITH DOTS:
%   %: (def) Months with dots
  mth-bare,%: Months without dots
%--------------------
%EDITION NUMBERS:
  xedn,%: Editions as in database
%   %: (def) Write out editions
% ord,%: Numerical editions
%--------------------
%Reading external language file \cfile=
%STORED JOURNAL NAMES:
%   %: (def) Full journal names
  jabr,%: Abbreviated journal names
% jabr,jaa,%: Abbreviated with astronomy shorthands
%--------------------
%AMPERSAND:
    %: (def) Use word `and'
% amper,%: Use ampersand
% varand,%: Use \BIBand
%--------------------
%COMMA BEFORE `AND':
%   %: (def) Comma before `and'
  and-xcom,%: No comma before `and'
% and-com,%: Comma even with 2 authors
%--------------------
%COMMA BEFORE `AND' EVEN FOR COLLECTION EDITORS (if using comma before `and' with authors)
% and-com-ed,%: Comma with 2 editors
%   %: (def) Two editors without comma
%--------------------
%NO `AND' IN REFERENCE LIST:
%   %: (def) With `and'
  xand,%: No `and'
%--------------------
%COMMA BEFORE `ET AL':
%   %: (def) Comma before `et al'
  etal-xc,%: No comma before `et al'
%--------------------
%FONT OF `ET AL':
    %: (def) Plain et al
% etal-it,%: Italic et al
% etal-rm,%: Roman et al
%--------------------
%ADDITIONAL REVTeX DATA FIELDS:
    %: (def) No additional fields
% revdata,eprint,url,url-blk,%: Include REVTeX data fields
%--------------------
%E-PRINT DATA FIELD: (without REVTeX fields)
    %: (def) Do not include eprint field
% eprint,%: Include eprint and archive fields
%--------------------
%URL ADDRESS: (without REVTeX fields)
%   %: (def) No URL
  url,url-blk,%: Include URL
% url,url-nt,%: URL as note
% url,url-nl,%: URL on new line
%--------------------
%REFERENCE COMPONENT TAGS:
    %: (def) No reference component tags
% bibinfo,%: Reference component tags
%--------------------
%EMPHASIS: (affects all so-called italics)
    %: (def) Use emphasis
% em-it,%: Use true italics
% em-x,%: No italics
% em-ul,%: Underlining
%--------------------
%COMPATIBILITY WITH PLAIN TEX:
  nfss,%: Use LaTeX commands
% plntx,%: Use only Plain TeX
%--------------------
  }}
\generate{\file{spcustom.bst}{\MBopts}}
\endbatchfile
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I needed. And thank you for the makebst trick

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that satisfies your requirements for the entry types you've mentioned. It uses `biblatex`. Probably for other entry types, there would remain some job to be done.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,french]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ham95,
Author = {C. Hamburger},
Issue = {Spring},
Journal = {Ann. Mat. Pura Appl.},
% Note{A very interesting paper},
Pages = {321–354},
Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
Title = {Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of partial differential equations},
Volume = {169},
Year = {1995}}
%
@book{aca92,
Address = {Boston},
Author = {K.O. Geddes and S.R. Czapor and G. Labahn},
Publisher = {Kluwer},
Title = {Algorithms for Computer Algebra},
Year = {1992}}
%
@incollection{broy02,
Address = {Heidelberg},
Author = {M. Broy},
Title = {Software engineering — from auxiliary to key technologies},
Editor = {Broy, M. and Denert, E. },
Pages = {10-13},
Publisher = {Springer},
booktitle = {Software Pioneers},
Year = {2002}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}% recommended in output (biblatex)
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle = numeric, firstinits, sorting = nyt, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0.4em}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}

\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{#1\isdot}

\xpatchbibdriver{article}{%
\usebibmacro{note+pages}%
}
{%
}{}{}
%
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}{%
\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
}
{%
\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
}{}{}
%
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}{%
\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
}
{%
\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
\setunit*{\space}\newblock%
\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
}{}{
}
%
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
\ifboolexpr{
test \ifuseeditor
and
not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
}
{\printnames{editor}%
\setunit{\space}%
\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}%
\clearname{editor}}
{}}
%
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\printlist{publisher}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\printlist{location}%
\setunit*{\space}%
\printtext[parens]{\printdate}
\newunit}
%
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
\usebibmacro{journal}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\iffieldundef{series}
{}
{\newunit
\printfield{series}%
\setunit{\addspace}}%
\usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
\usebibmacro{note+pages}
\setunit{\addspace}%
\usebibmacro{issue+date}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}
\newunit}
%
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
\printtext{\mkbibparens{%
\printfield{issue}%
\setunit{\addspace}%
\printdate}}%
\newunit}
%
\let\cite\parencite
%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Negotiation research spans many disciplines \cite{ham95}.
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]