# Looking for a bibstyle for biblatex I have never encountered

Tags: biblatex

A journal I like to submt to requires a bibliography style that appear do require lots of hacking. Before I start, I looked at the biblatex manual and it appears the style mingles different styles. Maybe somebody recognizes a known bibstyle from biblatex that corresponds to the examples:

Journal article

> Hamburger, C.: Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of partial differential equations. Ann. Mat. Pura Appl. 169, 321–354 (1995)

Article by DOI

> Sajti, C.L., Georgio, S., Khodorkovsky, V., Marine, W.: New nanohybrid materials for biophotonics. Appl. Phys. A (2007). doi:10.1007/s00339-007-4137-z

Book

> Geddes, K.O., Czapor, S.R., Labahn, G.: Algorithms for Computer Algebra. Kluwer, Boston (1992)

Book chapter

> Broy, M.: Software engineering — from auxiliary to key technologies. In: Broy, M., Denert, E. (eds.) Software Pioneers, pp. 10–13. Springer, Heidelberg (2002)

The citestyle is authoryear, no worries there. But the stuff above gives me a headache, especially that year all the way at the end and abbreviated journal names.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a *technical* journal and it doesn't have a LaTeX template?

Comment: No style will abbreviate journal names for you.

Comment: If a bibtex solution is OK, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188527/23160

Comment: Are you sure you need to conform to this to submit? In my field, most people worry about this only if their articles are accepted.

Comment: @mvkorpel - this link does the job, thank you for digging that one out - the link even proposes a solution for biblatex. Great. Thx